# Symmetric Matrices and Diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, symmetry

[image]

Hi, I am trying to figure this problem out, but I am having difficulty.

What I do know is that since A is symmetric,  then S must be orthogonal. Also that S^(-1) must equal S^t (Transpose). However i am not sure how to piece this information together.

Thoughts?

Comment: One useful description is that the columns of $S$ are eigenvectors of $A$. Do you see how to use this? (Hint: $A$ has rank $1$. What is the only non-zero eigenvalue of $A$? Eigenvector?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is $Av$?
$(vv^T)v = v(v^Tv).  v^Tv$ is a scalar and an eigenvalue of $A$.  $v$ is an eigenvector.

Can we guess at any of the other eigenvectors?
What about the remaining columns in R?  Suppose $v_2$ is a column vector in $R$ (and is not v).  Since R is normal $(v^T)(v_2) = 0$

S = R, and D has all zeroes along the main diagonals except in the first entry.

Comment: Is this because v^(T)v is the only eigenvalue?

Comment: 0 is an eigenvalue, too.